# resource classPath file convert to byte array not working

Tags: java, file, classloader, resteasy

Hi guys i trying to convert a pdf file to byte array but it dosn't work for me when i trying to get the file from the classPath resource using the classLoader and after that transform it to byte array it doesn't work i don't have a null array but the getting array length it's not ok and when i write this byte array as a file i have an damaged file and i can't opend it.

A last thing when i trying to get the file using the path like (c://java//files//test.pdf) it's working and byte array length it's ok and when i write the array as a file i have exactly the some file in input. another thing the getting file length using classLoader and using path is exactly the some 
My code is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            // convert file to byte[]
            byte[] bFile = readBytesFromFile("C:\\TEMP\\test.pdf");
            byte[] bytes = readBytesFromFileResources();

            System.out.println(bFile.length);//60255
            System.out.println(bytes.length);//14463
}
 private static byte[] readBytesFromFile(String filePath) {

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        byte[] bytesArray = null;

        try {

            File file = new File(filePath);
            bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];

            //read file into bytes[]
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(bytesArray);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        return bytesArray;

    }

    private static byte[] readBytesFromFileResources() {


        ClassLoader classLoader = ReadFile.class.getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("test.pdf").getFile());
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        byte[] bytesArray = null;

        try {
            bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];

            //read file into bytes[]
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(bytesArray);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        return bytesArray;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> A last thing when i trying to get the file using the path like
>   (c://java//files//test.pdf) it's working and byte array length it's ok
>   and when i write the array as a file i have exactly the some file in
>   input.

`c://java//files//test.pdf` is probably not in the classpath.
So, you cannot use the classloader to load the file as the classloader will not be able to find it.

Either you move the file in the classpath  (if it makes sense), either you load the file with the filesystem dependent way as you write in your question :

```
File file = new file("c://java//files//test.pdf)";
```

Comment: davidxxx think's for your answer but my need is to use the file place in resource folder i souldn't use path like "c://java//files//test.pdf" i juste use it like this to compare results

Comment: your are welcome :) My answer should answer to the question : "Either you move the file in the classpath (if it makes sense),"